# Data exchange mechanism between apps inside ESP32

Tags: publish-subscribe, toit

ESP32 can run and execute several applications in parallel. It is possible that they should interact with each other. Is there an alternative (other than PubSub) mechanism for exchanging data between apps inside ESP32, which would not be oriented on the use of cloud resources (topics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Toit only supports PubSub to talk between different applications on the ESP32.

There are plans to add a more efficient "RPC" mechanism to the framework, though.